# How to set jshint.options using gradle-js-plugin?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am using gradle-js-plugin version 1.9.0 and I am having trouble configuring global variables.  So far I've tried the following:

1. Creating the .jshintrc file in my project home directory.  .jshintrc file looks like:

   {
   "globals": {
       "NoesisCode" : false
   }
   }
2. Updating the jshint.options array inside the jshint configuration.

   jshint.options = [
           expr: "true",
           unused: "true",
           curly: "true",
           global: [
               "NoesisCode": false
           ]
   ]

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
jshint.predef = [
        "NoesisCode": false
]
```